# Adding Image on html table dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to adding image on html table dynamically using JQuery, but I am confusing how to find out a table 2,3..etc tr with in first td to add image.

My table structure has no id or class how to find, but before table have some text as below.

```html
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td colspan="2"><b>Order Details:</b><br> <br>
                <table width="100%" bgcolor="#EEEEEE">
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>Code</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>SKU</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Quantity</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Price</b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <b>Grand Total</b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>10172</td>
                        <td>Product 1<br></td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>
                            ₹ 50.00
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ₹ 250.00
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>10165</td>
                        <td>Product 2<br></td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td>
                            ₹ 50.00
                        </td>
                        <td>₹ 250.00
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right"> Subtotal: </td>
                        <td>₹ 250.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right"> Tax: </td>
                        <td>₹ 0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right"> Shipping Cost: </td>
                        <td>₹ 0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="right"> Grand Total: </td>
                        <td>₹ 250.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

How to Add product Image before of the SKU.

Any help plz..?

Comment: Where is __SKU__ in table?

Comment: @Satpal `Item` as `SKU` any way I have updated.

Comment: Your best bet is to change the html...

Comment: @freedomn-m, Yes, but we don't have above code we need to inject the product image through jquery.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have a `thead` or even use `th` for the headers, you'll have to skip the first row, you can use ">" to specify the direct hierarchy, eg:

```
$("table>tbody>tr>td>table>tbody>tr:not(:first-child)").each(function() {
    var codecell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");
    var img = "/pathtoimage/" + codecell.text() + ".jpg"
    codecell.after("<td><img src='" + img + '/></td>");
});
```

Updated: Fixed typo for `("td:eq(0)")` vs `("td").eq(0)` vs `("td")[0]`

Comment: @freedomn-m var codecell = $(this).find("td:eq[0]");
 should be
  var codecell = $(this).find("td:eq(0)");

Comment: @user3273700 thanks for pointing out the typo.  Updated answer.